# conformal mapping and derivative

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be analytic in $\mathbb{D}$, suppose $f(0)\in \mathbb{R}$, and$$f(\mathbb{D})\subset \Omega=\{z: |\Im(z)|<\frac{\pi}{2}\}$$
Show that $|f'(0)|\leq 2$.

I know that the conformal mapping $\frac{1-e^z}{1+e^z}$ maps $\Omega$ to the unit disk, and I need to do some composition with f to apply the schwartz lemma. But I can't find a good one that satisfies the condition of Schwartz lemma. can someone help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be interesting to note the condition $f(0)\in \mathbb R$ is not needed. I.e., any holomorphic map $f:\mathbb D\to \Omega$ satisfies $|f'(0)|\le 2.$ That's because the derivative estimate in the Schwarz Lemma can be improved from the one usually given: If $g:\mathbb D \to \mathbb D $ is holomorphic, then $|g'(0)|\le 1-|g(0)|^2.$ For the proof of this, let $a= g(0)$ and apply the usual SL to $\varphi_a\circ g,$ where

$$\varphi_a(z) = \frac{a-z}{1-\bar a z}.$$

Since $\varphi_a\circ g(0)=0,$ we get

$$|\varphi_a(g(0))g'(0)| = |\varphi_a(a))g'(0)| = \frac{|g'(0)|}{1-|a|^2} \le 1.$$

The estimate on $|g'(0)|$ follows. A corollary is that no matter where $g(0)$ is, $|g'(0)|\le 1.$

If we now have $f:\mathbb D\to \Omega,$ we can consider the map $ f(z) - \text { Re }f(0).$ (Subtracting off the real part makes the estimate easier.) Go through the same process that @ts375_zk26 presented, use the $|g'(0)|\le 1$ corollary above, and $|f'(0)|\le 2$ should fall out after some computation.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$
g(z)=\frac{1-\exp\left(f(z)-f(0)\right)}{1+\exp\left(f(z)-f(0)\right)}.$$
Since $f(0)\in \mathbb{R}$, $f(z)-f(0)\in \Omega.$ Therefore we have
$$|g(z)|<1\quad (z\in \mathbb{D}),$$
since the conformal mapping $\frac{1-e^z}{1+e^z}$ maps $\Omega$ to the unit disk.
Also $g(0)=0$, by which we can apply Schwarz lemma to $g(z)$ to get $|g^\prime (0)|\le 1.$
This leads immediately to $|f^\prime(0)|\le 2.$